# Auto create description in post

Tags: php, posts, customization, scripts

I want to create a script for when I add a title and an image to a post, and then when i publish, i want it to auto create a description

Something like . . . . .

You are viewing [title of post]! These are great hairstyle designs in our [category] section. Hope you try this look and feel on your hair today. Ever considered changing it up, you might like this [random post title and link]

This would be the body content of the post, In the last part it will select a random post and place his title and link (you might like this [random post title and link])

How can i achieve this using a php script and calling it from the publish button?

Comment: Please show what code you have tried so far. Sounds like most of what you're talking about pertains to template/theme development: http://codex.wordpress.org/Stepping_into_Templates

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `save_post_post` hook and use `$wpdb->update()` method. The code -

```
add_action( 'my_save_post_post', 'save_post_post' );
function my_save_post_($post_ID, $post )
{
    global $wpdb;

    $post_content = 'You are viewing '. $post->post_title .'! These are great hairstyle designs in our '. get_the_category_list( ', ', '', $post_ID ) .' section. Hope you try this look and feel on your hair today. Ever considered changing it up, you might like this';

    $random = get_posts( array(
        'post__not_in'    => $post_ID,
        'posts_per_page'  => '1',
        'post_type'       => 'post',
        'post_status'     => 'publish',
        'orderby'         => 'rand'
    ));

    if( $random )
    {
        $rpost = array_shift( $random );
        if( isset($rpost->ID) )
        {
            $post_content .= sprintf( 
                ' <a href="%s">%s</a>', 
                $rpost->post_title, 
                get_permalink( $rpost->ID )
            );
        }
    }

    $wpdb->update( 
        $wpdb->posts, 
        array( 'post_content' => $post_content ), 
        array( 'ID' => $post_ID ) 
    );
}
```

Comment: This seems really good, in which file this must be hardcoded?